# Yhwh: Exodus 3, 14. «I am that I am» and relationship to Metaphysics as Ontology?

Tags: history, tetragrammaton

The passage of Exodus 3:14, where God presents Himself as «I am that I am», is it historically previous to Parmenides, the greek philosopher?

I'm reading a manual on metaphysics as the ontology, and since like the name states, we're studying what is meant by 'to be'. If I'm not mistaken, this study of being, and 'to be' was started with Parmenides. I would like to know which came first, Scripture or the philosopher, and was there some influence between the two? Is this an analogous case to St.Paul's, where 'his' writings showed influences of a specific philosophy?

**Edit**
From some of the comments it seems that the passage of the Bible predates the philosopher by a millennium. If so, is there some evidence of a possible influence this seemingly seminal passage might have had on the origin of some greek philosophy?

Comment: This question is effectively asking a truth claim regarding the dating of the composition of Exodus - such a thing is outside of the remit of this site. Additionally, Paul's writings demonstrate a passing knowledge of Greek philosophy, but it is actually a tendentious opinion to baldly assert they are influenced by them.

Comment: According to Ussher, the event with the burning bush was 1491 BC.  Parmenides was born in 515 BC.  The saying of Numenius, the Pythagorean, as reported by Hesychius the Milesian was:  "Whatsoever Plato said concerning God and the world he stole it all from the books of Moses".

Comment: @bruisedreed, would it be so awful to state that Paul was influenced \textit{also} by the education he received, as long as what was taught truthful? Isn't the Truth only one?

Comment: @apocalypse_info_click_here, could you share some bibliographical references for that saying? Much obliged. ;)

Comment: It seems like your question is basically, does the accepted dating of Exodus predate Parmenides? If so, then I don't see why you are getting downvotes and votes to close. Short answer, yes, Exodus predates Greek thought by about a thousand years. However, the phrase "I am that I am" is mysterious. The Bible offers little explanation. It's cryptic almost. If it is similar to what Parmenides pondered, I would call that coincidence. But that is a different question.

Comment: @fredsbend I think they see this question as a passive-agressive one... I even felt some hidden hostility =D

This question was asked, because to me at least, this passage from the Bible is seminal to most of the metaphysics that came to us by hand of St.Thomas Aquinas. I was just interested in knowing if the bible might have influenced greek philosophy.

Comment: I don't think it would be awful, just inaccurate. You'd have a much stronger case if you were arguing that his training as a Pharisee 'influenced' him, but what does he actually say about that himself? He counts all his previous attainments of learning in that sphere as 'rubbish' or 'dung' - ie he disassociates himself from their influence in his bid to follow Christ (cf. Philippians 3) - this is the man who rejects conformity to the world's ideas but seeks for a transformed mind  according to the mind of Christ (cf. Romans 12:2).

Comment: Turning your question the other way like this doesn't really bring it back on topic here, if anything, it's further away now as its focus is more on Parmenides than the book of Exodus. As is, it could possibly be a better fit for either philosophy or history. PS I don't mean to come across in a hostile manner - apologies if you get that impression. And while I can't speak for others, I personally don't see your question as being passive-aggressive, in my view it's just ill-suited for this site the way you'd written it, according to the site guidelines.

Comment: @bruisedreed could you point me to the criterium according to which this question is not suitable for this forum?

Comment: I voted to close because your question was initally framed as a 'truth' question (see our Meta post [We can't handle the truth](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3527/we-cant-handle-the-truth) as to why this is off-topic). If I had to vote again on it now as is, I would still vote to close but under the option "General philosophical or sociological questions are off-topic unless clearly asking for a doctrinal answer." See also http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/types-of-questions-that-are-within-community-guidelines for more info.

Comment: @bruisedreed I don't see that option "General philosophical (...)" either in the links you posted, or in the flag options. Could you please tell me where I can find it? Thanks

Comment: It's a secondary option after "Off topic because...". The vote to close menu that's open to users of 3k rep and above may slightly different to the flag to close options open to users with less than 3k rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Exodus Bible Introductions by John MacArthur, Exodus was written in the 15th century B.C. http://www.gty.org/resources/bible-introductions/MSB02/Exodus . Also the archeological records support this according to https://bible.org/article/introduction-book-exodus

According to the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/parmenides/ and  Britannica http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/444361/Parmenides Parmenides lived a millennium later in 500 B.C

To answer your question who influenced who and which came first, the revelation of the name of God by God, Ehyeh-Asher-Ehyeh, came first.